# JPEG grey image with 8 bits single-channel

Tags: javascript, canvas, color-depth

I need to manipulate images but I need to set them as jpeg grey with 8-bit depth (single channel). Exist a way to make this using JavaScript or another JavaScript library, so all the development is made on the client side? I've tried to use canvas but the grey image jpeg is consider as 24 bits depth. Could someone help me?

Comment: The canvas is indeed not able to do it out of the box. So you'd have to generate yourself the jpeg file, which means having your own parser, which is, I guess you got it, too broad a question for SO. This leaves us with an "is a library that can do it" question, which is itself considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: I highly suggest reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking any more questions because with this one you didn't offer any relevant info, code, or an effort to do a little bit research yourself. In order for others to help you and for future visitors to take advantage of already existing answers, it all needs to be as clear as possible. Additionally, like @kaiido already said, this is too broad of a question for SO. Please read the article